# Everything is leading to an else instead of it reading the input

Tags: python

The code:

```
import math
import time
import os
from random import *

def intro():
    print("Welcome to battle. This is a game where you battle monsters.")
    print("You will try to get the highest score you can.")
    print("You start with 100HP. You will need to survive.")
    print("You get a max revive every 10 battles.")
    print("PS: This game is still in early alpha.")
    print("Bugs are expected.")
    game()

def game():
    health = 100
    revive = 0
    print("You are greeted by a monster...")
    print("1 = Fight")
    print("2 = Take a chance at running")
    choice = input("")
    if choice == 1:
        damage = randint(1,100)
        health = health - damage
        print("You killed the monster!")
        print("But you took "+damage+" damage")
        print("Your new health is: "+health)
    if choice == 2:
        print("You tried to run but failed.")
        damage = randint(70,100)
        health = health - damage
        print("Your new health is: "+health)
    else:
        print("Wrong choice. You died.")
        intro()
intro()
```

The problem: If you use 1 for choice it leads to else. Same with 2. Thanks to anyone that helps! PS: I am using Python 3. I don't know if that's important, I just need to fill out these lines.

Comment: Try `choice = int(input())` instead of `choice = input()`. Or alternatively change `if choice == 1` to `if choice == "1"`, same goes for `choice == 2`.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your input to `int`.

**Ex:**

```
choice = int(input())
```

and then replace

```
if choice == 2:
```

with

```
elif choice == 2:
```

*Edit as per comments*

```
def game():
    health = 100
    revive = 0
    print("You are greeted by a monster...")
    print("1 = Fight")
    print("2 = Take a chance at running")
    choice = int(input(""))
    if choice == 1:
        damage = randint(1,100)
        health = health - damage
        print("You killed the monster!")
        print("But you took "+str(damage)+" damage")     #-->Convert int to str before concatenation 
        print("Your new health is: "+str(health))        #-->Convert int to str before concatenation 
    elif choice == 2:
        print("You tried to run but failed.")
        damage = randint(70,100)
        health = health - damage
        print("Your new health is: "+str(health))       #-->Convert int to str before concatenation 
    else:
        print("Wrong choice. You died.")
```

Comment: Same thing with elif.

Comment: TypeError: must be str, not int

Answer (score 0):

You firstly need to cast your input to an int by using `int(input(""))`

Then:

You need to use `elif choice == 2:` instead of `if choice == 2:`.

Comment: Same thing with elif.

Comment: he needs to cast the input to int

Comment: TypeError: must be str, not int

Comment: You could just change to choice == "2", putting the number as a string :)